# Should I Throw ArgumentNullException if a string is blank?

Tags: .net

I'm working on a method that does something given a string parameter.  A valid value for the string parameter is anything other than null or string.Empty.  So my code looks like this.

```cs
private void SomeMethod(string someArgument)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(someArgument))
        throw new ArgumentNullException("someArgument");

    // do some work
}
```

Nothing too exciting there.  My question is, is it okay to throw an ArgumentNullException even if the string is equal to string.Empty?  Because technically it isn't null.  If you believe it should not throw ArgumentNullException, what exception should be thrown?

Comment: Throwing ArgumentNullException when string is "" is misleading.

Comment: I agree, alas the reason I've previously done it this way is because of the answer "Joe" gave, it is used like this in the .net framework code.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

[ArgumentException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception.aspx) should be thrown for the `String.Empty` case. This would indicate an issue other than it being null. To avoid a `NullReferenceException` I check for null first, then I trim and check for the empty case to prevent any whitespace from passing.

```
private void SomeMethod(string someArgument)
{
    if(someArgument == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("someArgument");

    if (someArgument.Trim() == String.Empty)
        throw new ArgumentException("Input cannot be empty", "someArgument");

    // do some work
}
```

As of .NET 4.0 you can use the `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` method to perform these checks in one go. By doing so you forgo the ability to specify a granular exception type, so I would opt for the `ArgumentException` and update the message accordingly.

Comment: I'm using C# 2.0, the only reference to InvalidArgumentException is in the Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common namespace, is what you recommend or are you suggesting that I create my own InvalidArgumentException class?

Comment: @Keith: you're correct, my mistake. You could write your own if you're so inclined or use the ArgumentException provided by the framework. I'll edit to reflect the proper name.

Comment: The ArgumentException constructor doesn't take a "paramName" parameter like ArgumentNullException. So 'throw new ArgumentException("paramName")' is potentially confusing, as it doesn't give any indication what's wrong with the argument.  You should be providing a "message" argument something like ("someArgument may not be an empty string").  And in an international app this message would need to be localized.  Hence I would only go to all this trouble if there is really a need to distinguish the null case from the empty string case.

Comment: @Joe: in this case perhaps the constructor that takes 2 string parameters would be more appropriate, the 1st being the error message and the 2nd being the parameter that caused the exception (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sxykka64.aspx). This would result in: throw new ArgumentException("Input cannot be empty", "someArgument");

Comment: " ... perhaps the constructor that takes 2 string parameters ..." - yes absolutely, either constructor that takes a message parameter would do, but if you're using it in more than one place the constructor with a paramName parameter is better.

Comment: Joes point is valid for any exception.  As a user one of the most annoying things is an exception message that doesn't [really] give you any information.  _All_ exceptions should have a message with as much information as is pertinent, preferably the message should offer possible solutions.  My pet hate is the "File not found" message, what file isn't found?

Comment: You could also try: if ( String.IsNullOrEmpty( someArgument ?? string.Empty ) ) {} but that would get quite cluttered.

But I would agree that you should write one for each case.

Comment: @Mark true, although that wasn't introduced until .NET 4.0 and this question was asked before that time.

Comment: If you don't mind the same exception being thrown in either case (and I'd argue that would be more useful than the current answer where the user sees "Input cannot be empty" only if the input is non-empty and filled entirely with whitespace) then it might be cleaner to write just one conditional expression: `if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(someArgument) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(someArgument.Trim()))`, making use of the conditional OR that only evaluates the second expression if the first is false. Although like has already been pointed out, `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`, if available, is better again.

Comment: Your first statement and your code are not consistent with each other, presumably from an edit to your answer? You're throwing ArgumentNullException for the string.Empty case, and only throwing ArgumentException for non-empty whitespace strings.

Answer (score 5):

You should throw an `ArgumentException` if an empty string is not an accepted input for your method. It may be very confusing to clients if you throw an `ArgumentNullException` while they didn't provide a `null` argument.

It is simply another use case. You may also have methods that do not accept null input values but that do accept empty strings. It's important to be consistent across your entire application.

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of ArgumentOutOfRangeException but maybe that is used for array index range exceptions.

Comment: For array index exceptions, IndexOutOfRangeException is used. You should use ArgumentOutOfRangeException only if your method is documented to accept only a specific collection of strings (e.g.: "abc", "def", "ghi" are the only accepted inputs).

Comment: Microsoft's own documentation seems to provide conflicting advice on IndexOutOfRangeException/ArgumentOutOfRangeException topic. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.argumentoutofrangeexception?view=netcore-3.1#remarks
Perhaps this is where they are heading, but I tend to agree with @ronald-wildenberg on their use

Answer (score 3):

Taking all the things into account that have been said (Joe / Ahmad Mageed), I would create an exception for that case then.

```
class ArgumentNullOrEmptyException : ArgumentNullException
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to derive from ArgumentException? In OOP, saying that "A or B" is an "A" doesn't seem right.

Comment: @dcstraw ArgumentNullException derives from ArgumentException. In this case I think it's better ArgumentNullOrEmptyException  derive from ArgumentNullException.

Comment: Also I think its name should be StringArgumentNullOrEmptyException because it only has a meaning for string arguments.

Comment: Or... If it handles ICollection too, its name can be ArgumentNullOrEmptyException.

Comment: ArgumentNullOrEmptyException : ArgumentException    In the rare case that you want to catch ArgumentNullException, the programmer should have to treat this case differently since it might be empty.   
E.g. with C# 8, you may need to thrown, catch and wrap/rethrow ArgumentNullException caused by external code passing in a null where your code assumes a non-nullable input.  ArgumentException from empty string would not be processed same way

Answer (score 2):

ArgumentNullException is sometimes used in the .NET Framework for the String.IsNullOrEmpty case - an example is `System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetText`.

So I think it's reasonable to do the same in your code, unless there is some real value in distinguishing the two cases.

Note that this and other exceptions derived from ArgumentException generally indicate a programming error, and therefore need to provide information needed to help a developer diagnose the problem.  Personally I think it's unlikely that a developer would find it confusing if you use ArgumentNullException for an empty string argument, especially if you document this behavior as in the example below.

```
/// <summary>
/// ... description of method ...
/// </summary>
/// <param name="someArgument">... description ...</param>
/// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException">someArgument is a null reference or Empty.</exception>
public void SomeMethod(string someArgument)
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't look to Windows Forms for examples of the latest best practices in .NET Framework code. I was able to quickly find a counter example in File.Copy(string, string), which throws ArgumentNullException for null and ArgumentException for empty.

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but since Google ranks it highly, here's another (better!) option for future readers: `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

`ArgumentException` is the base class for both `ArgumentNullException` and `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`, amongst others. That means it's more generic and less informative to developers who are handling the exception. In other words, whilst all `ArgumentNullException`s and `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`s are also `ArgumentException`s, the reverse is not true.

`ArgumentOutOfRangeException` is a more specific exception which says "the value you provided was not in the range of values I expected", which is exactly what you're trying to tell other developers. It's the best standard exception type if you won't accept an empty string.

Alternatively, create your own exception type derived from `ArgumentNullException`, if it's really important to distinguish between values.

When handling your exception, other developers who don't need to distinguish why the value they supplied was wrong can just catch `ArgumentException` and get them all at once.

Comment: There’s some discussion of why not to use the `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` under @ronald-wildenberg’s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1355973/3025856). Does that change you’re thinking at all on this?

Comment: In short, no. That answer asserts "You should use `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` only if your method is documented to accept only a specific collection of strings", but offers no reason as to why "range" should be defined as "specific set". A specific set is a range, as is "everything except A, B..." etc. Personally, I would also use the exception message to explain why the value is considered out of range in this specific case. But essentially, if your method does not handle a specific input value, it is "out of range" of the expected/handled values.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on circumstance really.

The question comes down to, is it really an error? By that I mean do you **always** expect a value? If you do, then probably your best bet here is creating your own `Exception`, perhaps like so:

```
class StringEmptyOrNullException : Exception
{
}
```

Where you can also add your own constructors and added information etc.

If it however is not an "exceptional" happening in your program, if would probably be a better idea to return null from the method and handle it from there. Just remember, `Exception`'s are for exceptional conditions.

Hope this helps,

Kyle

Comment: If you *do* create your own exception, it should derive from ArgumentException rather than Exception.

Comment: Depending on context really, in this context yes. If you want to use it in other places, you make it more generic. For instance if you have a method that generates a string that shouldn't be empty, ArgumentException won't be the best choice. So, depending on the amount of use you have for it, and the context in which it is used, you will then decide on what to inherit from.

Comment: IMO those are two different situations - method generating a string and an argument passed into a method, and I would prefer to have two different exception types. It is better to be verbose than jam multiple kinds of error situations into a single exception.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use this code?

```
private void SomeMethod(string someArgument)
{
//chek only NULL
if(ReferenceEquals(someArgument,null))
    throw new ArgumentNullException("someArgument");

// and after trim and check
if (someArgument.Trim() == String.Empty)
    throw new ArgumentException("Input cannot be empty", "someArgument");

// do some work
}
```